# slim framework and ajax. '/' character as a parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, slim

I'm making an ajax call to a Slim framework web service. This is for sending notes to my database.

The problem is that the users can write for example "send 1/2 piece". So when I make the call, the URL throws 404 not found because of the '/' character.

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

```
notes = 'send 1/2 piece'

$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://Myserver/orders/notes/' + MyOrder + '/' + notes,
            dataType: "json", // data type of response
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
            },
            success: function(data){
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
                errorPopup(errorThrown);                    
            },
            complete: function(xhr, status){
            }
        });
```

Comment: `EncodeURI` / `EncodeURIComponent`

Comment: EncodeURIComponent not working for me. It just encodes the full URL and still I get 404

Comment: GET is not the best method to send arbitrary data. I would consider using POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run EncodeURIComponent against notes, only.

Before your ajax call:

```
notes = 'We have funny characters in here like /es';
encNotes = EncodeURIComponent(notes);
```

Then, create your url string using the encoded string.

```
url: 'http://Myserver/orders/notes/' + MyOrder + '/' + encNotes,
```

Comment: I get the same error: http://Myserver/orders/notes/PV1600484/send%201%2F2%20piece 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please post the code where you declare your GET route